# PIC32MX220 won't enter UART Rx interrupt handler

Tags: pic, uart, interrupts

I'm new to the PIC32 and have been trying to get the UART to enter the ISR when it receives a byte on the Rx pin. My UART setup works fine both sending and receiving (if I use blocking to read the received byte), but I want to use interrupts to achieve a more "real-time" feel (since the PIC is doing a bunch of other stuff).

This is my code for configuring the uart and Rx interrupt:

```
INTCONbits.MVEC = 1;
     
// Peripheral Pin Select    
U1RXRbits.U1RXR = 2;    // Set PA4 to RX
RPB15Rbits.RPB15R = 1;  // Set RB15 to TX
    
// UART1 Configuration
U1MODE = 0;
U1MODEbits.PDSEL = 0;
U1MODEbits.STSEL = 0;
U1BRG = Baud2BRG(9600);

// Configure UART1 RX Interrupt
IEC1bits.U1RXIE = 0;    // Disable interrupt
IFS1bits.U1RXIF = 0;    // Clear the interrupt flag
IPC8CLR = 0x001f;       // Clear priority vector
IPC8bits.U1IP = 7;      // Set priority
IPC8bits.U1IS = 3;      // Set sub priority
IEC1bits.U1RXIE = 1;    // Enable the interrupt

// Enable UART1
U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;
U1STAbits.URXEN = 1;
U1MODEbits.ON = 1;
```

And for handling the interrupt:

```
extern "C" {
    void __ISR( _UART1_VECTOR, ipl7SOFT) uartRxHandler(void)
    {
        IEC1bits.U1RXIE = 0;    // Disable the interrupt

        Serial1Tx( "works");

        IFS1bits.U1RXIF = 0;   // Clear the interrupt flag
        IEC1bits.U1RXIE = 1;   // Enable the interrupt
    }
}
```

I just send a simple message back to see if it ever gets into the ISR. I can't understand why the interrupt is never triggered. Thanks for any assistance.

I'm using MPLAB X with the XC32 compiler and a PICKit3 to program.

Comment: What is the full part number of your pic?

Comment: I'm using the pic32mx220f032b

Comment: Do you have other interrupts confirmed working? (Just checking that you have globally enable interrupts in the co-processor)

Comment: How many bytes are you receiving? Is the baud rate of both the same? Check for any error status that may be occurring like I overflow, parity error etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem almost 10 years later, I found this thread and no answer. They I discovered we did the same mistake. We picked the wrong registers for the priority/subpriorty, they should be `U1RXP` `U1RXS` not `U1IP`/`U1IS`.